# Qt, C++: QGraphicsScene coordinates are not working

Tags: c++, qt

I've checked a lot of solutions, but can't find one that would be working for me.

I have QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView in my app:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
space = new QGraphicsScene(this);
spaceView = new QGraphicsView(space);
spaceView ->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft);
}
```

I also have button, that runs function:

```
void MyWindow::addWidget()
{
    myWidget *w1= new myWidget(space);
    space->addItem(w1);

    myWidget *w2 = new myWidget(space);
    w2->setPos(10,10);
    space ->addItem(w2);
}
```

It adds two obiects, but the second one should be on different coords(moved by (10,10)).
When I'm not using:

```
spaceView ->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft);
```

Moving works, but all items are in center of my view - I don't want to have it centered. I need it positioned from upper-left corner. After using "setAligment" code that I showed above changing position do nothing. Two obiects are in the same place. Can someone tell me how can I get positioning from upper-left corner and make it possible to move it around?

I don't want to use:

```
space->setSceneRect(i.e. 0,0,1000,1000,Qt::);
```

becouse I don't want to limit my scene on the right side.
I also tried to use:

```
spaceView->fitInView();
```

but it also wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get positions and bondings of `scene` using functions:

```
QGraphicsItem::sceneBoundingRect()
QGraphicsItem::scenePos()
```

All items add for first in position `(0,0)` and after this are transformed into the right position. You can work with `GraphicsView` coordinate system and use coordinate mapping from the view to the scene. To do this, use:

```
QGraphicsView::mapToScene()
QGraphicsItem::mapToScene()
```

or

```
QGraphicsView::mapFromScene()
```

for get position on scene

Comment: Your sugestions to use functions for checking bounding helped me to find out why my obiect wasn't changing position. In myWidget I have another obiect that is drawed on scene and to change it's position I just had to use "w2->rect2->pos(10,10);".

Thank you for these helpful functions